# How to use activex control in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, activex

i want to add active-x control in asp.net webpage.i am try to searching on Google but till not getting pro-pertly ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveX controls dont depend on the server side technology, they depend on the <object> tag on the server side unless you want to use it on the server side. In that case you want to use COM Interop for ex.
Generally you need to generate the proxy to access the library - assuming server side.

http://www.thinketg.com/company/blogs/blogs/jasonworley/posts/11-07-22/NET_COM_Interop_with_VB6_ActiveX_DLLs.aspx

there are manyyyy posts out there on this. Are you looking for client side or server side?

Comment: M fresher on developing..i wanna to add activex control into web page..is this possible??according to me activex control use in window application.but i try so much to show in web page.and i thnk dats activex control only run at IE6.                                                                I have check out ur link and got some more things about activex.   @Adam..Do u have any demo file of activex control use in web page??so i got proper understand of this topic.

Comment: well which ACtiveX control? you have server side activex controls and client side objects